# Ubuntu 22 Display localtime instead of universal time

Tags: time, ntp, timezone

I want to display local timezone instead of Universal time in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. It also displays same UTC +00 in all regional timezone. I did set time timezone manually nothing works.

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Kathmandu
sudo timedatectl set-ntp on
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnUOw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rbrx.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing works" ?

Comment: It should display local time in top center of the screen but shows universal time instead

Comment: Did you try to log out and log in?

Comment: Yes., I did. It still shows the inverted time displayed in top center.